# Best way to select data created_at=Today || created_at=Yesterday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

All the data in my app updates every day at 12:00am, but it might take some time till that data is updated(1, 2h).

Because of that I need to to check if the data for today is present, if is not take the data from yesterday.

What is the best way of doing this?

Till this point I created scopes and methods to do that, but I know that there it should be a better way.

```
@project.landings.today.present? ?
  @project.landings.today : @project.landings.yesterday
```

I am looking for a methods which it can be shared with multiple classes and improves the performance if possible, considering that almost every view is checking to see if data is present.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Don't you like the way the code reads? Don't you like that style? Are you looking for a more performant way? What?

Comment: You could add a boolean `latest` column to mark the most recent data for each project and use an appropriate scope, e.g. `@project.landings.latest`